# Reducing HtmlUnit Library jar size

Tags: jar, obfuscation, proguard, htmlunit

Hi I have  written a script using HTMLUnit that fetches a web page given a url and performs certain operations on them. For instance searching for a string on a page or clicking on a link and so on. I am creating a runnable jar using eclipse IDE.

HTML-Unit consists of about 21 different library jars that i am extracting in my single final runnable jar. These dependencies cause the single jar to occupy a space of about 9.3MB. I have been trying to reduce the individual jar size using obfuscation. I am using a tool called proguard for it.

Here is a sample proguard configuration i am using to obfuscate a single library  jar by the name of "commons-logging-1.1.1.jar":

```
 `-libraryjars  <java.home>/lib/rt.jar

  -injars       C:/Users/Desktop/Jars/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar

  -outjar       C:/Users/Desktop/SmallJars/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar

  -printmapping C:/Users/Desktop/SmallJars/out_commons-logging-1.1.1.map

  -renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile

  -dontnote

  -keepattributes InnerClasses,SourceFile,LineNumberTable,Deprecated

  -keep public class * {
   public protected *;
   }

  -keepclassmembernames class * {
   java.lang.Class class$(java.lang.String);
   java.lang.Class class$(java.lang.String, boolean);
   }

   -keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
    }

   -keepclassmembers class * implements java.io.Serializable 
    {
    static final long serialVersionUID;
    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);
    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream);
    java.lang.Object writeReplace();
    java.lang.Object readResolve();
    }`
```

The config is pretty much the same as one given on the proguard website in usage -> typical libraries. On rebuilding the project in eclipse using these 21 reduced jars and running it, the script fails at runtime with the exception:

"java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createDefaultSSLContext()"

Looks like i have obfuscated the individual jars in a manner that certain methods will now not be found. Could you guide me as to what may be causing these exceptions. and is there something wrong with the config file above.If
so what would be the best proguard configuration for this scenario.

I am aware another member was chasing a similar problem. The question is posted at link:

[a link] ([Determine used libraries to reduce JAR file size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460757/determine-used-libraries-to-reduce-jar-file-size))

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method is accessed by reflection, which ProGuard can't know from its static analysis. You have to preserve it in your configuration. Cfr. ProGuard manual > Troubleshooting > [NoSuchMethodException](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#nosuchmethodexception).

Processing the application as a whole will be much more effective than processing the libraries individually, because ProGuard may then remove entirely unused libraries or at least larger parts of them.